# Импортозамещающая или импортозамещаемая продукция?

Tags: лексика

Власти Москвы составят перечень **импортозамещаемых** товаров в строительстве.

Это хорошая и всем понятная инициатива, **но только что на что будем замещать**, как бы не ошибиться?

Существует термин "импортозамещающая продукция". Есть понятие импортозамещения - это   тип экономической стратегии, направленный на защиту внутреннего производителя **путем замещения импортируемых промышленных товаров** товарами национального производства.

Тогда правильное соответствие следующее: замещать импорт и замещать импортом -  импортозамещающий и импортозамещаемый. Или нет?

**Здесь надо решить грамматическую задачу, правильно обозначив:**

1) товары, которые замещают (**могут** заместить) импорт. Это импортозамещающие  (импортозаместимые?) товары.

Еще вариант объяснения: импортозамещаемый продукт - это **взаимозаменяемый** с точки зрения "импорт-национальный продукт"

2) Товары, которые **нельзя заместить** импортом.  Это импортонезаместимые товары.

Другой вариант: неимпортозамещаемый продукт - это **невзаимозаменяемый** с точки зрения "импорт-национальный продукт"

Answer (score 1):

> Тогда правильное соответствие следующее: замещать импорт и замещать
>   импортом - импортозамещающий и импортозамещаемый.

Возможное понимание:

***импортозамещаемый*** -- производимый за рубежом, импортируемый  в Россию; тот, который предполагается заменить производимым в России (т. наз. *импортозамещающим*);

***импортозамещающий*** -- аналог импортируемого в Россию товара (т. наз. *импортозамещаемого*), производимый в России.

Comment: Тогда "Власти Москвы составят перечень импортозамещаемых товаров в строительстве" - это неправильно?

Comment: (Откорректировал свой ответ.) Если под _импортозамещаемым_ понимать товар, производимый за рубежом, то составить _"перечень импортозамещаемых товаров в строительстве"_ можно.

Comment: Значение слова должно ясно считываться с его морфемного состава, а не являться задачей с разными трактовками.

Comment: Да морфемы-то не всегда помогают. Вспомните недавний Ваш вопрос по слову "пошлый". Просто, на мой взгляд, нужно, чтобы законодатель ли или кто иной, употребив какое-либо новое, ранее не употреблявшееся слово, сам разъяснил, какое значение он в него вкладывает. Слова **импортозамещаемый** я нигде в приличных документах найти не сумел, понимать его можно как угодно, а потому лучше было бы, на мой взгляд, слово это пока не использовать, а замещать его словами, которые всем понятны.

Comment: Используют слово  "импортозамещающий"   с вполне понятным значением: были импортные комплектующие (иглы, кабели, электроды и др.), а сейчас надо заменить отечественными, например: "Перечень импортозамещающей продукции, необходимой отечественным предприятиям-изготовителям". Здесь морфемный состав понятен, особого объяснения не требуется. Но берем слово "импортозамещаемый" - и уже непонятно, что меняется, и слово подчеркивается как неверное. Вот я могу придумать выражение "цветозаменяемая схема", такого слова нет, но его значение понятно без словаря: меняются разные цвета (друг на друга).

Comment: _Vera: Вот я могу придумать выражение "цветозаменяемая схема", **такого слова нет, но его значение понятно без словаря**: меняются разные цвета (друг на друга)._ === 

Сказать по правде, я не только из самого выражения "цветозаменяемая схема", но из из Вашего пояснения этого выражения не сумел понять, что же это такое -- _цветозаменяемая схема_. И чем эта схема будет отличаться от _"цветозаменяющей схемы"_.

Comment: Ну это схема, в которой  элементы могут менять  цвет, графики температур например. Или все цветовое оформление меняется  - такая цветоуправляемая схема.

Comment: Я тоже не понимаю этого слова без определений (скорее, приписал бы ему смысл "схема, в которой выбранные цвета можно заменить другими, необязательно связанными с имеющимися в ней), но в случае "замещения" (в моём понимании) корень указывает на односторонний характер замены (замещение крови, должности, дорогого дешёвым и т. п.), подстановке чего-то доступного на место другого, здесь -  с целью обойтись без него. Поэтому "взаимозаменяемость" в рассм. словах не заложена. Это создаёт проблему образования слова для "потенциально замещающего" импорт ("импортозаместимый" даёт  обратный смысл).

Answer (score 1):

Импортозамещаемый - "замещаемый импортом". Отечественный продукт, не выдержавший конкуренции с дешевым и/или качественным импортным товаром. 
Импортозамещающий - "замещающий (кого/что?, В.п.) импорт". Отечественный продукт, дождавшийся наконец запрета импорта и вдохнувший полной грудью государственных живительных преференций.

Comment: По логике вещей (и грамматики в том числе) всё правильно. Но у нас особая логика, и нужно как-то эти особенности обозначить.

Comment: Да, действительно, теперь поняла значение этих слов и то, почему slava1947 не понимал смысла слова импортозамещаемый в контексте предыдущего вопроса. Вторая часть сложного слова _импортозамещающий_ говорит о том, что сам товар замещает собой импортный (действительный залог). А в слове _импортозамещаемый_ эта часть указывает на страдательный залог, т. е. на то, что товар замещается импортом.